# Grouping JavaScript Objects and Customization

Tags: javascript

I have the following implementation and its functional

https://jsfiddle.net/9mv6w0da/

**Input**

```
dataSet[0].data= [
    {color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow", weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow", weight:12}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red", weight:13}
];          
dataSet[1].data= [
    {color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow", weight:12}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"blue",weight:11}
   ,{color:"blue",weight:11}
];
```

**Current Output**

```
an[0]=[
   {color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
   ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
]
an[1]=[
    {color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
   ,{color:"red",weight:13}
]
an[2]=[{color:"blue",weight:11},{color:"blue",weight:11}]
```

I would like to add  `{color:null, weight:null}`
 when I group data from different javascript objects.

*Pseudo code:*
   dataSet[0] (color, weight)+**{color:null, weight:null}**+dataSet[1] (color,weight)

If you take a look at desired output, `an[0]`, first `three objects` comes from `dataSet[0`] and the last `two objects` comes from `dataSet[1]`. When I am combining them, I would like to add `{color:null, weight:null}`

**Desired Output**

```
an[0]=[
       {color:"yellow",weight:12}
       ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
       ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
       ,{color:null, weight:null}
       ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
       ,{color:"yellow",weight:12}
    ]
    an[1]=[
        {color:"red",weight:13}
       ,{color:"red",weight:13}
       ,{color:null, weight:null}
       ,{color:"red",weight:13}
       ,{color:"red",weight:13}
    ]
    an[2]=[{color:"blue",weight:11},{color:"blue",weight:11}]
```

Comment: I don't think it is very clear as to when `{color:null, weight:null}` has to be added. Can you please explain `group data from different javascript objects` a bit more ?

Comment: If you take a look at desired output, an[0], first `three objects` comes from `dataSet[0`] and the last `two objects` comes from `dataSet[1]`. When I am combining them, I would like to add `{color:null, weight:null}` Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: so `an[2]` does not have `null` because both the values (blue) it has are from the **same** dataset ?

Comment: Exactly! I think now you have got my question clearly.

Comment: the problem is, after `allData` is created, each item has lost a reference to its parent. Meaning, by looking at `{color:"yellow",weight:12}` it cannot be said if this is from dataSet0 or 1. One solution I can think of is to make each entity have a reference about its parent before `allData` is created. For example: `{color:"yellow",weight:12, dataSet:'0'}`

Comment: Is "don't do that" a bad answer?  an array is not the data structure you're looking for if you want a delimiter.

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, you are free to approach the problem if there is an easy/better way to do that you could ignore my existing code. I know existing code always restricts others. I am open to your approach as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adding extra attribute to indicate what is the array number and after that put that logic (adding extra object ) into groupby method.

```
var i = 0 ; 
var dataSet1 = dataSet.map(function(obj){
obj.map(function(objj){
    objj.arrkey = i ; 
    return objj;
});
i = i+1;
return obj;

});


function groupBy(arr, f) {
 var result = {};
 var arrKey = {} ; 
 arr.forEach(function(elem) {
 var fElem = f(elem),
    list = result[fElem] || [],
    arr = arrKey[fElem] ; 

  if(arr === undefined){
      arr = elem.arrkey;}

if(elem.arrkey != arr)  
{ 
    list.push(nullobj);
}
list.push(elem);
arrKey[fElem] = elem.arrkey;
result[fElem] = list;
});
return result;
}
```

Example in https://jsfiddle.net/5swdjg3f/

Answer (score 0):

```
combined = data1.concat ([{color: null, weight: null}]).concat (data2)
```

But don't do that.  Use an array of arrays where each source has its own sub-array, or better yet, write a class with a method that clearly spells out why those sets are separated, because the next guy on this code doesn't know what the `null`y element indicates.  He also can't group things by some other criteria without digesting your delimiters and adding his own, which will be equally hack-y.